# Is a loginway PIC-01 development board enough to program a PIC?

Tags: pic, development, board

I have a loginway PIC-01 Development board (it was sat in a cupboard for years).

Does this board require additional adaptor hardware to blow a PIC (ICSP stuff etc), or can the on board serial port be used to do that?

Comment: Just noticed you have questions in the topic and expansion that are opposite senses. Makes the "yes" answer quite ambiguous. Good thing I wrote more than that...

Comment: Yann - I've rephrased that question to make it clearer what I meant. The answer does mean additional hardware is needed - but is comprehensive enough to be marked as the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it requires additional hardware to program a new PIC (as indicated in the [manual](http://loginway.com/pdf/manual.pdf)). [PICkit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2519&param=en534451&page=wwwdevMPLABEmulatorDebuggers) is one such with good features for the price, including debugging, serial communication and logging. Once you have a way to program your PIC, it can communicate through the serial port; this could be used to implement a [bootloader](http://www.etc.ugal.ro/cchiculita/software/picbootloader.htm) in self programming capable chips, the way boards like Arduino work. Your Loginway PIC-01 is a pretty good host board to build on, and certainly more featureful than the host board in the PICkit bundle.

Comment: Hmm - I've now found this link http://www.electro-tech-online.com/microcontrollers/29943-help-pic-01-development-board.html - where some helpful chappy has posted a schematic. Handy - since the loginway documentation is a bit sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it and buy a Microchip PICkit 2 or 3 (under $50). They offer debugging as well as programming, and the latter supports all the current devices.